# how to initialize a sem_t variable

Tags: c++, linux, semaphore, sem

I am getting a seg fault at sem_init. I am trying to create a unnamed sem. Thank you
Appreciate some help on this.

```
sem_t *t;

int status = sem_init(t,1,1);
```

Comment: Ask yourself: what is `t` pointing to?

Comment: Never dereference a null or uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Offtopic: I really recommend to master basics of C++ before even attempting anything what is related to multiple threads. It will save you lots of time and frustration. Note also this is C API specific for Linux, C++ has own API for that.

Comment: sem_t is a typedef

Comment: typedef union{ char size[size]; loing int; }sem_t;

Comment: https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/bits/semaphore.h.html

Answer (score 3):

```
sem_t t;

int status = sem_init(&t,1,1);
```

This is C API, so all functions use pointers, not references.

Furthermore there are no constructors, hence the existence of `sem_init` which is used to initialize a structure object `t`.

It doesn't allocate an object, double ptr would be needed for that.

See e.g. `man 3 sem_wait` for an example.